# Add attributeSet but based on an existing set - Magento

Tags: php, magento

Ok, its possible to add a new attribute set in magento using something like the following:

```
$entitySetup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup;
$entitySetup->addAttributeSet('catalog_product', $setName);
```

But how can i base the set on an existing set like the default.   This option is available in the admin section so its possible.

Answer (score 3):

I did this 6 months ago, I do not have the code anymore, but I know you have to use the [initFromSkeleton()](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Eav/Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Set.html#initFromSkeleton) method on your attribute set. You can search Magento's code for calls to this function, there are very few calls (just one perhaps). It will show you its usage.

EDIT: I remember I had the very same problem you are talking about, and I mailed about it. Here is the usage I was advised:

```
$attrSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set');
$attrSet->setAttributeSetName('MyAttributeSet');
$attrSet->setEntityTypeId(4);//You can look into the db what '4' corresponds to, I think it is for products.
$attrSet->initFromSkeleton($attrSetId);
$attrSet->save();
```

The initialization is done before the save.

Comment: Heres the thing though, in the admin section when you hover over the link for the default attribute set, the id shows as 4.  When i call Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
       ->load($setName, 'attribute_set_name'); the attribute id is returned as 1.  Therefore when calling initFromSkeleton the the default group is 4 and not 1 so no attributes are associated

Answer (score 3):

```
            // create attribute set
            $entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')
                ->setType('catalog_product')
                ->getTypeId(); // 4 - Default

            $newSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set');
            $newSet->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);
            $newSet->setAttributeSetName(self::ATTRIBUTE_SET_NAME);
            $newSet->save();

            $newSet->initFromSkeleton($entityTypeId);
            $newSet->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

```
$i_duplicate_attribut_set_id = 10; // ID of Attribut-Set you want to duplicate
$object = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Set_Api();
$object->create('YOUR_ATTRIBUT_SET_NAME', $i_duplicate_attribut_set_id);
```

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find useful information about [working with attribute sets](http://www.addonbakery.com/blog/2011/11/working-with-attributes-in-magento/).

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')
    ->setType('catalog_product')  // This can be any eav_entity_type code
    ->getTypeId();
$attrSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set');

$attrSetCollection = $attrSet->getCollection();
$attrSetCollection
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', array('eq' => $entityTypeId))
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name', array('eq' => 'Default')); // This can be any attribute set you might want to clone

$defaultAttrSet = $attrSetCollection->getFirstItem();
$defaultAttrSetId = $defaultAttrSet->getAttributeSetId();

$attrSet->setAttributeSetName('Assinaturas'); // This is the new attribute set name
$attrSet->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);
$attrSet->initFromSkeleton($defaultAttrSetId);
$attrSet->save();
```